# How do I hide folders in OSX?

Tags: macos, folders

Is there a way to hide folders in OSX like you can in Windows? And if so then how?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### The command-line way:

Open Terminal (/Applications/Utilities) and type

```
chflags hidden /path/to/folder
```

replacing `/path/to/folder` with the POSIX-style path to the folder you want to hide (for example, a folder on your desktop called test would be `~/Desktop/test`).

To unhide it, type `chflags nohidden /path/to/folder`.

### The freeware way:

I haven't used it, but I've seen the app [Hide Folders](http://www.altomac.com/hide_folders/index.php), by Altomac.

Answer (score 4):

Any file or folder that begins with a . will be hidden by default, although you can use a utility like [TinkerTool](http://www.bresink.com/osx/TinkerTool.html) to override this.

Comment: Unfortunately, in 10.6, Finder won't let you rename something to start with a .

Comment: @Nathan Terminal lets me rename files to start with a ., but you're right that Finder does not.

Comment: Hm, maybe that's another feature of TinkerTool or something else I've added, as I'm able to rename files in the Finder with a beginning dot. But using `mv` in Terminal is always available, as per @Troyen

Answer (score 0):

In terminal enter the following to show hidden folders:

```
defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles TRUE; killall Finder;
```

This will make all hidden folders visible, and will also allow you to prefix a folder with "." directly from finder (making it hidden).

To hide folders again, enter the following:

```
defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles FALSE; killall Finder;
```

Comment: If you don't want to always be opening terminal and typing this in, make an automator command so you can assign it to a hotkey or menu option or something.