# Is it safe to delete a user's "Downloads" and "Documents" folders in OS X?

Tags: macos, terminal, mojave

When attempting to delete my user account's "Downloads/Documents" folder, I get a beep and nothing happens. But I figure I could probably get rid of them in Terminal with a `sudo rm -f`...am I right? And would this break the OS in any way?

I don't use those folders at all (downloads from my browser go straight to my desktop, and that's where I keep most of my user docs too) so this would be good to be able to do in the interest of keeping the computer as clean as possible, and also being able to autocomplete "Desktop" with a single `D<Tab>` keystroke in Terminal. Thanks!

UPDATE: Thanks to those who suggested workarounds in the comments, but I'm not interested in **pretending** that those folders don't exist; I want them **gone**! If that's not possible, then no worries, thanks anyway :-)

Comment: I don't think you can delete standard folders. You can hide them from the Finder, though. See https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/15979/how-do-i-hide-folders-in-osx and https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/25932/move-pictures-documents-movies-etc-folders

Comment: How can you possibly "keep your computer clean" if you use your desktop like a Windows user? Why not allow the Mac to assist rather than fight it?

Comment: You can attempt to reduce encountering Downloads and Documents by removing them from the sidebar and setting "Open new tab with" Desktop, both in Finder Preferences. Hope you find out the autocomplete thing too .

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as duplicate of https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/25932/ https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/15979/
https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/144914/
https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/115646/
https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/100341/ Basically, all in Linked in the sidebar

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Move 'Pictures', 'Documents', 'Movies' etc folders](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/25932/move-pictures-documents-movies-etc-folders)

Comment: @Tetsujin LOL I know it's anal but I like **everything** to be **my** way on **my** computer. By "clean" I mean "no folders/files that I and the OS don't explicitly need", rather than "not looking messy". And the autocomplete thing is pure laziness...but when you type "De<tab>" 5 times a day, every day it starts to become inpreferable to "D<tab>". I know it's only one keystroke, but it builds up into an annoyance over time (for someone as anal as myself :P)