# Any way to stop creating 'TV' folder in ~/Movies on macOS Catalina

Tags: macos, mac, catalina

Since macOS Catalina, I have a default 'TV' (Apple TV) app installed on my Mac.

It regularly creates an 'TV' folder inside `~/Movies` with a file 'TV Libary' and an empty folder 'Media'.

I like to keep my filesystem clean, so I want to get rid of this 'TV' folder. However, when I manually delete the folder it comes back after some time.

Is there any way to stop the automatical creation of the `~/Movies/TV` folder?

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/373276/is-it-safe-to-delete-a-users-downloads-and-documents-folders-in-os-x#comment501128_373276

Comment: I don't see how that question is relevant / links in your comment on that question are duplicates of this one. I'm not trying to delete it, I'm trying to stop it from being automatically created. https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/15979/how-do-i-hide-folders-in-osx might be useful, however, that's just hiding it and not fixing the problem of automatically creating that folder. @ankii

Comment: Oh I assumed that you have an issue with Movies Folder itself.

Comment: Oh, right. Well, the link that you've posted here had an link to another question (https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/15979/how-do-i-hide-folders-in-osx) and that answer (hiding the folder) actually helps! So, thanks :) @ankii

Answer (score 5):

Short answer? Yes and no.

You can tell TV.app to change where it will store its library by opening the app, going into preferences and then under Advanced choosing a new location. This may not move the current folder, but will create a new one in a location that you prefer, so you can freely get rid of the one under `~/Movies/TV`.

However, if you don't have a TV.app library, and never open the app, then once you delete the folder it *should* stay gone. Of course if you do open the app, it will be recreated, this may also occur if you enable home-sharing for that account, even if you're only sharing music.

Comment: It should stay gone, however, it won't. I never use TV.app, so I don't get why it keeps reappearing.

Comment: What I did was: `chflags hidden ~/Movies/TV` to make the folder hidden. I can't stop the folder from reappearing eventho I do not use the TV app. Best thing to do is hide the folder, so it's out of sight, out of mind.

Answer (score -1):

Open Finder, right click on Movies on the sidebar, and then go to "Get Info". Lock the folder from there. Unlocking is the simply unchecking that box. The folder would be unmodifiable for most purposes.

Comment: This won't fix my problem, at all. I want to use the `~/Movies` folder.